# CSS - automatic div width

Tags: css, html, css-float

I have html structure that can change depending on the page context. On some pages looks like:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="column">
    blah
  </div>    
</div>
```

And on others:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="column">
    blah
  </div>    
  <div class="column">
    blah
  </div>    
</div>
```

So, the container has a fluid width (100%).

The `.column` div is fluid too, and should have the width of its container in the first example, ie. 100%, 
and in the second example 50% width and aligned to left.

Like:

```
----------------------------
|                           |
|         column1           |
|                           |
-----------------------------
```

and

```
----------------------------
|            |              |
|  column2   |  column2     |
|            |              |
-----------------------------
```

How can I do this?

I should also note that I can't change any markup within column1/column2 (can't add classes or anything like that, maybe only using javascript hacks or capture the php output and using regex :)

Comment: Can you add classes to the .column elements via javascript?

Comment: yes, but I'm really trying to avoid such solutions. You would get a "delay" before the layout gets fixed

Comment: I agree, but you said you couldn't "add classes or anything like that," but you did entertain the idea of "using javascript hacks" so I assumed you had no access to the CSS/Markup, but you did have access to scripting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can think of two solutions.

1. Use [CSS3 flex box](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/).
2. Set the columns to `display: table-cell;` on the columns and `display: table-row;` on the container.

Comment: The table display method would be great, but it doesn't seem to work, I get one column above the other. Are there any restrictions for using table-cell/table-row?

Comment: nevermind, I had a float I had to remove, it works now. probably not in IE but I don't care. thanks!

Comment: Actually, starting with IE8 the table display modes should work fine. You can check the whole compatibility table and more info on it at Quirksmode (http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html).

Answer (score 1):

The best I can come up with is JavaScript: http://jsfiddle.net/V5Au7/.

Some pretty annoying gotchas:

1. This assumes that the only divs in the #container are the ones with the class name of "column."
2. This assumes that the columns have no borders, padding, or margin.
3. [You could run into sub-pixel problems, by relying on percentages.](http://ejohn.org/blog/sub-pixel-problems-in-css/) Of course, this probably won't be a problem if you stick with just one or two columns.

There's gotta be some CSS-only way that can also work in IE6. I can feel it, I just can't find it.